# Clear file before writing in it StreamWriter (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I using stream writer to write generated code to file

Here is code

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("generated-codes.txt"))
        {
            foreach (String s in passwords)
                writer.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

How I can clear file before writing to it.

Application is .NET Core 2.1 solution

Answer (score 4):

Use [`File.CreateText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext) instead of [`File.AppendText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 3):

Use `File.CreateText` instead of `File.AppendText`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=netframework-4.7.2